# Google AJAX Feed API, Dynamic Feed Control and the Japnese Language

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine

English is fine but for Japanese feeds its showing invalid characters...

why i am getting invalid characters in Japnese feeds?
http://acsjapan.jp/j/index.html

not in english?
http://acsjapan.jp/

help me fix for japnese feeds..

Comment: Please explain in detail what you're doing and what the problem is. Consider showing some code.

Comment: please chck the code there, japnese characters are not showing up http://acsjapan.jp/j/index.html (right-down panel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an encoding issue.

You are using (implicit) `ISO-8859-1` encoding on your web page. Your AJAX feed serves `UTF-8` characters.

This is tricky: I don't think you can make the Google Service deliver its data in the ISO-8859-1 character set. The best way would be to switch your site to UTF-8 - but that may have deeper consequences, and require other changes, especially if you are using a CMS.

Mandatory basic reading: [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Comment: thanks a tonn UTF-8 FTW can u please return my 3 pts i think the question was clear..